# "#1054 - Unknown column..." при выполнении SELECT запроса

Tags: sql

Есть запрос:

```
SELECT SUM( `square` ) 
FROM `reports` 
WHERE `username` = Иван
```

Вылетает

> #1054 - Unknown column 'Иван' in 'where clause'

Почему так?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Нужно взять Иван в кавычки:

```
SELECT SUM( square ) FROM reports WHERE username = 'Иван'
```

Answer (score 0):

А если столбец будет называться не username а, например, key. При запросе выводит ошибку:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'key = "config_image_cart_height" LIMIT 0, 30' at line 1
```

Как быть в этом случае?

Comment: Это поле только для ответов. Задайте новый вопрос.